# calculate lifetime value based on monthly intervals from the time they first purchased

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate a lifetime value but based in intervals of the number of months from when they first purchased. In other words, what is the average lifetime value of a customer in their first month, second month, third month etc...

mysql table structures looks like this:

```
id|customer_id|  total  | date
--------------------------------------------
1 | 80        | 2178.00 |2015-01-02 15:10:35
2 | 100       | 540.00  |2015-05-08 17:03:16
3 | 122       | 5940.00 |2015-05-26 10:16:02
4 | 899       | 423.00  |2015-05-14 11:44:07
5 | 128       | 1740.00 |2014-09-08 17:26:06
```

This is how I'm currently thinking this needs to happen:

I need to find the first order date for the customer which is done by

```
select DATE(MIN(date)) as firstOrder
```

Then I need to add x days or months from that first date using something like

```
DATE_ADD(firstOrder, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Then find the total between those two dates for each customer divided by the number of customers, like:

```
firstMonthsTotalRevenue / totalNumberOfCustomers = firstMonthsLTV
firstAndSecondMonthsTotalRevenue / totalNumberOfCustomers = secondMonthsLTV
```

I'm trying to do as much via mysql but could break it up into multiple queries, and format it with php if I need to, just trying to be as effective as possible.

The end result might look like this

```
Month | LTV
1     | 100.00
2     | 200.00
3     | 250.00
4     | 300.00
5     | 325.00
```

The LTV would always be growing, because it's taking the revenue from all previous months, ideally I would be able to calculate this with x day intervals or weekly intervals as well.

Any help is appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

I've got this, so far, it helped just writing out exactly what I was looking for:

```
select format(sum(monthOne.total) / count(*),2 ) as monthOneLTV 
    from (select sum(total) as total, orders.customer_id as customer_id, internalTable.firstOrder
        from orders join 
            (select DATE(MIN(`date`)) as firstOrder, customer_id from orders group by customer_id) as internalTable on orders.customer_id = internalTable.customer_id
        where orders.date between internalTable.firstOrder and DATE_ADD(internalTable.firstOrder, interval 1 month)
        group by customer_id)  
    as monthOne;
```

With this, it just finds the first months, and if I wanted the entire year I would then have 12 queries, incrementing interval 1++ month. Also I don't know if this is the most efficient way to go about this.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/498d07/5

Comment: If your number of customers increases during these periods, the LTV could go down, no? If in January here's only one customer, who spent $100, then LTV = 100. Now in February 10 new customers spend each $10, then the LTV for February = (100 + 10*10)/11 = 200/11 = 18.89

Comment: @trincot thanks, for looking at this, then numbers wouldn't go down because it's wouldn't be February's numbers it would be total revenue from month 1 and 2 divided by the same number of customers as in month 1, if nobody ever purchased in month 2, then it would stay the same, but never go down

Comment: So the spending of customers that had their first order *after* January, does not count at all? Or does it, but it is still divided by the number of customers on 1 January of the year? That sounds like a weird statistic if you ask me.

Comment: @trincot, ya it's a little strange to explain, but biz case would be to figure out when is my break even point on average for my customers, if it takes $500 to get a customer (advertizing, sales etc), how many months on average will it take to have that customer spend $500 with the company to break even, then what's potential profit point after that. 

To answer your question, don't think of it as Jan, Feb etc.., think money spent in first month of being a customer, by end of second month etc... also I updated post with an update.

Comment: I still don't understand: do you need a fixed starting point in time? Because I think you need it for determining which customers you are including in the calculation, and which not. You seem also to have two different time axes: one for how long a period you look at per customer, and which absolute period in time you want to limit yourself to. I mean, I don't think you are still interested in a first months performance in 2003. It is not at all clear to me what you are looking for. It would be good to work out an example with sample data.

Comment: Correct we could add an additional logic for the first order date has to be after certain period of time or between two dates. I created a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/498d07/5

Comment: So for the 1 month average you would not mind if for one customer that month was in early 2015, while for another that month was just passed, or even is still not over? You would all add them together for one average, and then repeat for 2 months, ...etc. So your report would maybe have 19 lines (for up to 20 months of period - Jan 2015 to July 2016).

Comment: @trincot Yes that's correct